# Rails: Cookies with Net::HTTP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, cross-domain

I have two rails applications **App1** and **App2** both running on separate URLs but on same machine. **App1** fetch some data using `Net::HTTP` from **App2**. What I need to do is to set a `cookie` in **App2** when request is made from **App1**. Currently, it's not setting the cookie. Do I need to add some header in App1 while sending request to **App2**, or what?

Here is the code to fetch the content:

```
def get_content(url)

    uri = URI.parse(url)

    params = Hash[*uri.query.split("&").map {|part| part.split("=") }.flatten]

    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path)
    request.set_form_data( params )
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new( uri.path+ '?' + request.body )

    if uri.scheme == "https"  # enable SSL/TLS
      http.use_ssl = true
      http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
    end
    http.start do
      http.request(request) do|res|
        return res.body
      end
    end
end
```

Please advice.

Comment: I would think, possibly incorrectly, that since you're doing a direct http request, you have to manage cookies in the header on your own.

Comment: Okay fine, but how can I do it on my own? Any example would be greatly appreciated. thanks.

Comment: http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=21943

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first question: Where do you want to place the cookie? On the client who is browsing your website?

Is your request flow like:

Client --[web browser]--> App 1 --[net::http]--> App2

If this is the flow, you have to proxy the cookie:

```
def get_content(url)

    uri = URI.parse(url)

    params = Hash[*uri.query.split("&").map {|part| part.split("=") }.flatten]

    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path)
    request.set_form_data( params )
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new( uri.path+ '?' + request.body )

    if uri.scheme == "https"  # enable SSL/TLS
      http.use_ssl = true
      http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
    end
    http.start do
      http.request(request) do |res|
        # yummy, parse some cookies here
        app2_cookies  = CGI::Cookie.parse(res['Set-Cookie']);

        app2_cookies.each do |c_name, c_cookie|
          # this is the cookies object from rails! Make sure this is accessible here!
          # the cookie will now be set on the client side
          cookies[c_name] = c_cookie.value
        end

        return res.body
      end
    end
end
```

Make sure you require CGI::Cookie

Here are the docs:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/classes/Net/HTTPHeader.html#M001307

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/classes/CGI/Cookie.html#M000170

Comment: Thanks Sled. I truly appreciate your effort. I'll give it a try and let you know the results.

Comment: although it's settings the cookie but setting for App1 from where is the request is being made. I need to set and access cookie from App2. Could you please guide me?

Comment: app2 has no direct connection to the web browser and can not set a cookie directly. If the App2 runs on a different **domain** it is impossible to do it directly because of security restrictions. If this is the case you need to do a proxy request from App2 to App1 using Net::Http.

Comment: App1 and App2 are running under different domains.

Comment: I am under TIGHT deadline. I'd be obliged if you could help me get rid of this problem. Thanks again.

Comment: How to make the proxy reqest from App2 to App1 in above flow?

Comment: if app1 and app2 are running on the same server and you have access to both there are a handful of options: 1. Create a shared data store 2. Share the cookie using an iframe 3. Do the same with net::http from the other side 

I don't know what you want to do with the cookie sharing, maybe you can give me more information.

Comment: Yes, both are running on same server and I have full access to server.

Comment: @Imran let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1853/discussion-between-sled-and-imran)